# Errno = 13 and how to debug this more efficiently?

Tags: android, debugging, errno

I'm making an application and when i go from menu to an other activity that display image using the e3roid framework, i allways get this (logcat):

```
D/PhoneWindow( 1562): DebugMonitor class=com.recisio.kfandroid.gui.tab.KFFeaturedTab focus=false
E/copybit    ( 1562): Error opening frame buffer errno=13 (Permission denied)
D/PhoneWindow( 1562): DebugMonitor class=com.recisio.kfandroid.gui.player.KFPlayer focus=true
```

I'm questionning myself about **where does the error come?
Is there a way to know exactly where it happens?
May i have to ignore this?**

Apparently, copybit is just an abstraction for a basic 2D blitter with support for rotation, scaling and color/pixelformat conversions.

But where it's strange it's that all the images loaded appears well on my screen.

Ok: I tried to change the way i was encoding the bmp I print like this:

```
return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap_width, bitmap_height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
```

but it doesn't solve the problem.

By printing several display infos everywhere in my code i realised that the error happens while loading the e3roid engine.

I'm going to look at the sources while waiting for more answers.

After some tests with printing a bmp i create before (valid), I get this

```
E/copybit ( 3274): Error opening frame buffer errno=13 (Permission denied)
D/dalvikvm( 3274): GC freed 3337 objects / 132024 bytes in 150ms
I/DEBUG   ( 1145): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   ( 1145): Build fingerprint: 'vodafone_fr/htc_buzz/buzz/buzz:2.1-update1/ERE27/183733:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   ( 1145): pid: 3274, tid: 3519  >>> com.recisio.kfandroid <<<
I/DEBUG   ( 1145): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):  r0 46c62008  r1 00000000  r2 00100000  r3 00000018
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):  r4 4685fd10  r5 00000002  r6 46c62008  r7 0000000c
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):  r8 00000000  r9 4191fd20  10 00000de1  fp 002e4428
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):  ip 80000000  sp 4685fc98  lr acc9697b  pc afe0e060  cpsr a0000010
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):          #00  pc 0000e060  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):          #01  pc 00016978  /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):          #02  pc 00016d5a  /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):          #03  pc 0002886c  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):          #04  pc 0000f3f4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1145): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1145): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   ( 1145): afe0e050 0a00000a e1530002 8202301c e1b0ce03 
I/DEBUG   ( 1145): afe0e060 28b100f0 48b10300 28a000f0 48a00300 
I/DEBUG   ( 1145): afe0e070 e3130004 1491a004 1480a004 e0422003 
I/DEBUG   ( 1145): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1145): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   ( 1145): acc96968 5c39008f 434b6936 435a1c30 f7ed6921 
I/DEBUG   ( 1145): acc96978 e020e91a fef4f7ff 28001c05 480fd101 
I/DEBUG   ( 1145): acc96988 69c2e01a 47901c31 1c2169ab 47981c28 
I/DEBUG   ( 1145): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1145): stack:
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):     4685fc58  001615b8  [heap]
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):     4685fc5c  00000800  
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):     4685fc60  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):     4685fc64  acc97fdb  /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):     4685fc68  00301418  [heap]
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):     4685fc6c  acc9604d  /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):     4685fc70  00010002  [heap]
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):     4685fc74  00100000  [heap]
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):     4685fc78  00000200  
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):     4685fc7c  00000200  
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):     4685fc80  001615b8  [heap]
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):     4685fc84  acc95f3d  /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):     4685fc88  afe38e08  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):     4685fc8c  afe0eed4  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):     4685fc90  df002777  
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):     4685fc94  e3a070ad  
I/DEBUG   ( 1145): #00 4685fc98  00000002  
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):     4685fc9c  46c62008  
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):     4685fca0  0000000c  
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):     4685fca4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):     4685fca8  4191fd20  
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):     4685fcac  00000de1  
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):     4685fcb0  002e4428  [heap]
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):     4685fcb4  46c62008  
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):     4685fcb8  4685fd10  
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):     4685fcbc  acc9697b  /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1145): #01 4685fcc0  4106788c  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):     4685fcc4  002e4428  [heap]
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):     4685fcc8  ad053c19  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):     4685fccc  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):     4685fcd0  ad080f8c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):     4685fcd4  00300ea0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):     4685fcd8  00000200  
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):     4685fcdc  001615cc  [heap]
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):     4685fce0  00000001  
I/DEBUG   ( 1145):     4685fce4  acc96d5f  /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1145): debuggerd committing suicide to free the zombie!
I/DEBUG   ( 3535): debuggerd: May 28 2010 02:08:39
```

**What is this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm..I guess your device supports ARGB_8888 because all the images 
loaded well on your screen. OpenGL sometimes shows strange errors when 
the device encounters low memory situations.

Comment: I think it was that, but i let e3roid down to use canvas instead ;) Ty

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error some times ago, it was due to a lack of memory. In the emulator logcat and not on my phone (wildfire) it was saying: `OutOfMemoryException`.

Make sure you use the `recycle()` nethod to clear bitmap from the memory.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you are using a not supported texture format. Try using a RGB565. Here you can find some info about the issue: http://code.google.com/p/processing/issues/detail?id=391