# Error opening frame buffer errno=13 (Permission denied)

Tags: android

I have an android application which runs without problems on a Samsung Captivate i897 and on an HTC Sensation 4G, but when I run it on an HTC Desire X (Stock ROM), it writes this message into the LogCat:

```
Error opening frame buffer errno=13 (Permission denied)
```

and the `AsyncTask` does not executes.

I use some images from internal memory. Everything worked before, what may be problem?

Comment: `it writes this message into the LogCat` ... which message?

Comment: @DerGolem `Error opening frame buffer errno=13 (Permission denied)`

Comment: Please post your COMPLETE LogCat as an addiction to your question

Comment: @DerGolem it has tag `copybit` and is a comlete LogCat.

Comment: If you don't put more info (on which method crash, etc..) it's a very generic question without info...

Answer (score 0):

The problem maybe is similar to this question: [Errno = 13 and how to debug this more efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105247/errno-13-and-how-to-debug-this-more-efficiently/7178244#7178244)

Maybe HTC Desire X has less memory than the other two.